# Find $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+35}-6}{x-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

I've rationalized the numerator to
$x^2+35-36$

$$= \frac{x^2+35-36}{(x-1)\left(\sqrt{x^2+35}+6\right)} = \frac00$$
(when I substitute $x=1$)

I don't know what to do to the denominator so I can substitute $x=1$ to find the limit.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying it at all?

Comment: I've simplified to x^2+35-36 / (x-1)(sqrt(x^2+35)+6

Comment: Well, that's not simplified enough. For example, you've left $35 - 36$..........

Comment: good point, i'll watch for that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1:**
$$35 - 36 = -1$$

**Hint 2:**

You know that the numerator is $0$ when you substitute $x=1$. That means that $(x-1)$ is a factor of the numerator:

$$x^2+35-36 = (x-1)(\ \ldots\ )$$

You can then cancel out $(x-1)$ from top and bottom. (But simplify first using Hint 1.)

Comment: x^2+35-36 = (x-1) (x+1)

Comment: @Jessica There you go!

Comment: (x+1) / (sqrt(x2+35)+6). Then do I just substitute 1 in for x to find the limit as x approaches 1?

Comment: @Jessica Yes, and you will see that you now get an actual number as opposed to $0/0$. This number is the limit you're looking for. As a test, you could try substituting $x=1.0001$ (for example) in the original expression and it should give you approximately the same thing.

Comment: Thank you! (I should have brushed up on my algebra before jumping into calc)

Comment: @Jessica You're welcome! It's just a matter of practice. :)

Comment: Any good websites I can use to brush up on algebra skills?

Comment: @Jessica I'm not sure myself. You could post this as a new question; the community will be able to help you out. Make sure to specify what level of algebra you're looking for (i.e., to go along with introductory calculus).

Answer (score 1):

You already have been given good answers to the problem.

Let me show you another approach which can be of interest (even just for your curiosity at the present time).

To make life simpler, set $x=1+y$. This makes

$$A=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+35}-6}{x-1}=\frac{\sqrt{y^2+2 y+36}-6}{y}$$ Consider the first portion of the numerator $$\sqrt{y^2+2 y+36}=6 \sqrt{1+\frac y{18}+\frac {y^2}{36}}$$ Since $y\to 0$, term $y^2$ is very negligible and then $$\sqrt{1+\frac y{18}+\frac {y^2}{36}}\approx \sqrt{1+\frac y{18}}$$ May be, you already know that for small values of $z$, $\sqrt{1+z}\approx 1+\frac z2$ (you can easily check it with a pocket calculator). So $$\sqrt{1+\frac y{18}+\frac {y^2}{36}}\approx \sqrt{1+\frac y{18}}\approx1+\frac y{36}$$ All of that makes $$A\approx\frac{6(1+\frac y{36})-6} y=\frac{6+\frac y{6}-6}y=\frac 16$$ which is the limit.

Answer (score 0):

You may check about l'hospitals rule. If limit of both numerator and denominator tend to zero, you differentiate the numerator and denominator with respect to the variable to which you apply limit.

By doing that you 1/6 I guess.

Check the following link

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html

Comment: A student asking this question is extremely unlikely to know what L'Hospital's rule is. Furthermore, considering that this is the definition of the derivative of $\sqrt{x^2 + 35}$ at the point $x = 1$, using that rule is circular at best.

Comment: yea, no idea what your talking about here we just started limits Monday